# How to skip a Service class if the Spring profile is different than one specified, using the annotation @Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, javabeans

I have a service class marked with the annotations:

```
@Service(value="myService")
@Profile("test")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
 ...
 }
```

Therefore if the current Spring profile is "test" the methods of this class will be used for the service myService.
While, I would like also to have another class with the same annotations maybe with `@Profile("!test")` that be be loaded in all other cases when the profile is not test, 
 How can I do that without configuring anything in the .xml Spring configuration files? I would like to use simply annotations.

Comment: Have you just tried that? The `!` feature was in the works experimentally, and I think it made it into 4.

Comment: yes I have, it does not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define another bean like so:

```
@Service(value="myServiceDefault")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
 ..

}
```

Then change your initial code for the test profile to:

```
@Service(value="myService")
@Profile("test")
@Primary
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
 ...
 }
```

What this does is register an implementation for all profiles to use and then when the test profile is active is uses the other implementation because of the @Primary annotation

If you are using Spring 4 you could come up with even more elaborate configuration strategies using the @Conditional annotation

Comment: Ok, but I need services with the same names, it should be transparent to the client. In your example you are using 2 different names `myServiceDefault` and `myService`

Comment: You can use the same name, there is no problem. The @Primary annotation makes Spring select that service over others

Comment: I have just tried your solution with the annotation `@primary` and `@profile("test")` in the same class using the same services names, but in my tests the first service is loaded. Maybe I will end up with the `@Conditional` annotation

Comment: Are you using the @ActiveProfiles annotation in the tests?

Comment: Could you upload your code to some sharing service? Something else must be wrong because I have done what I have described many times

Comment: I can't sorry, but I followed exactly your instructions with spring 4, doest matter I will use the `@conditional()` annotation

Comment: @daniele Ok, no problem

Comment: btw, I cant use the `@Conditional(MyConditionImpl.class)` annotation because in `MyConditionImpl` I should autowire the environment (or implements EnvironmentAware) and it won't work, it will fail on loading

Comment: You don't need to inject the environment. Is it available in the methods of matches. Check out this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-conditional

Comment: Thanks @geoand I am often so busy that I do not have time to read the documentation, thank for reading it for me :) it works

Comment: @daniele I know the feeling of not having enough to time to read the docs :)